# Python for loop syntax with two dimensional array

Tags: python

```
for f in train.columns:
    missings = train[train[f] == -1][f].count()
```

what does `trainp[][]` mean? How can this be two dimensional array if f referring to another column?

Comment: What does this syntax mean in numpy or pandas?

Comment: @alexpdev That's valid Python syntax. `numpy` and `pandas` are just frameworks written in Python so what's valid for `numpy` or `pandas` must also be valid for Python.

Comment: @alexpdev You're confusing syntax error with other types of exception. The OP's code and your example are both valid Python syntax.

Comment: If you are posting a code, Format it as a code please

Comment: @alexpdev It was responded within the context of your comment with the "syntax error" claim, which you have conveniently deleted yourself. Good to see that you have accepted my point.

Answer (score 1):

It's looking like you are already getting values from the 2D array i-e train[train[f] == -1][f]

you can make it a 2D array by doing something like that

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
```

or

```
    arr = [[12, 13, 5, 4], [14, 8,11], [12, 10, 12, 6], [15,17,9,0]]
```

Answer (score 1):

For vanilla python It is certainly very odd and poorly written code, but it could be valid in a very limited number of situations.  Below are a couple examples in which it would work.  I am sure there are more, but either way it is not very easy to understand and I do not recommend using it in your own code.

Note: the `iterable.count()` method requires 1 argument.

example 2

```
f = 4
train = [[1, 2, 3, 4, [0, 0, 1, 0]], [1, 2, 3, 4, [1, 0, 1, 1]], 0, 1, -1]
missings = train[train[f] == -1][f].count(1)
print(missings)  # output = 3
```

example 1

```
f = 4
train = {True: [1, 2, 3, 4, [0, 0, 0, 1]], False: [1, 2, 3, 4, [1, 1, 1, 0]], 4: 1}
missing = train[train[f] == -1][f].count(1)
print(missing) # output = 3
```